# What's the correct way to use an array in a JavaScript RegExp?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use a Regular Expression on an array of strings in JavaScript.

```
let item1 = "Low-income families";
let item2 = ["Low-income families"];
let item3 = ["Low-income families", "LatinX/Hispanic", "Children and youth", "Rural"];

let key = "Low-income families";

console.log(new RegExp(item1, 'giu').test(key) || key === '') //Prints true
console.log(new RegExp(item2, 'giu').test(key) || key === ''); //Prints true
console.log(new RegExp(item3, 'giu').test(key) || key === ''); //Prints false
```

My question is, why does `item2` return `true` with that regular expression, but `item3` return `false`? What would be the correct way to perform the regular expression on the array so that `item1`, `item2` and `item3` all return `true`?

Comment: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-isregexp might have something to do with it. I'm assuming `item2` gets converted into a pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`item1` and `item2.toString()` give the same result (a string, with no characters that have special meaning in a regex, that is an exact match for `key`).

`item3.toString()` doesn't give a string that is an exact match for `key`, nor does it give a substring of it.

You seem to be under the impression that passing an array to the `RegExp` constructor will create a "match any item in this array" expression, but it does *absolutely nothing like that*.

You might want to be using [`item3.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) instead.

Comment: Thanks this helped. I got confused when item2 worked and I didn't realize that arrays in JS have an explicit toString() method written. Also, wasn't perfectly clear that the constructor for `RegExp` was taking in a String.